# Angular route doesn't catch the url when rendering url from ServerSide (Nodejs)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, single-page-application, mean-stack, angular-routing

I'm a beginner to Mean-stack web development. I'm working on my university project that should develop as a single page application based on MEAN Stack.
     I have link all angular resources, css and other links in index.html. login and home page coded inside s only. 
     Problem is If login authentication is success, I want to display Home page using angular routing when server-side respond as url of Home {res.render('/home')} but this way doesn't work. But login page work properly. any help would be much appreciated.

---

This index.html--

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="../server/angModule.js"></script>
      <script src="../server/angularRoute.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="Pharmacy">
        <div ng-view > </div>
    </body>
```

---

This login.html

```html
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Login</button>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember-me"> Remember me
    </form>
```

---

This is Angular module , routing and controllers

```js
var app = angular.module('Pharmacy', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '../views/login.html',
    controller: 'loginController'
  }).when('/home', {
    templateUrl: '../views/home.html',
    controller: 'homeController'
  }).when('/about', {
    templateUrl: '../views/about.html',
    controller: 'studentController'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/"
  });
});

app.controller("loginController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.login = 'this is login';
});

app.controller("homeController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'This is home';

});
```

---

This is necessary server side codes;

```js
var UH       = require('./modules/userHandaling');
module.exports = function(app) {

 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
 });
 app.get('/index', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
 });
 app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  if (req.cookies.user == undefined || req.cookies.pass == undefined){
   res.render('index', { title: 'Hello - Please Login To Your Account' });
  }else{
   // attempt automatic login //
   UH.autoSignIn(req.cookies.user, req.cookies.pass, function(o){
    if (o != null){
     req.session.user = o;
     res.redirect('/home');
    } else{
     res.render('index', { title: 'Hello - Please Login To Your Account' });
    }
   });
  }
  res.render('index');
 });
 app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  UH.manualSignIn(req.body['username'], req.body['password'], function(error, output){
   if (!output){
    res.status(400).send(error);
   } else {
    req.session.user = output;
    if (req.body['remember-me'] == 'on'){
     res.cookie('username', output.username, { maxAge: 900000 });
     res.cookie('password', output.password, { maxAge: 900000 });
    }
   res.render('/home');
   }
  });
 });
```

---

Also I have uploaded my project on Github : https://github.com/SarasaGunawardhana/StackOverFlow-Question

Thank you friends .

Comment: make sure your if-else working fine using console.log in login route method

Comment: all are work fine brother.. there is no any problem in there.. perfectly return results. problem is angular routing. login.html is viewing inside index.html file. but when it comes to home.html , I coudnt get to view inside Index file

Answer (score 0):

Change `res.render('/home');`  to `res.render('home');`

Comment: good point bro, I tired then it just gives basic home,html file without viewing inside index.html. also url will not change to "/home". when using res.render('/home'); command i gives this ERROR:  Failed to lookup view "500" in views directory "C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\Mastercoders\views" ;

Comment: How about res.redirect('/home')?

Answer (score 0):

You should render your template to client side like this,

```
res.render('home');
```